# LEFT JOIN order and limit

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, sql-order-by

This is my query:

```
SELECT `p`.`name` AS 'postauthor', `a`.`name` AS 'authorname',
       `fr`.`pid`, `fp`.`post_topic` AS 'threadname', `fr`.`reason`
  FROM `z_forum_reports` `fr`
  LEFT JOIN `forums` `f` ON (`f`.`id` = `fr`.`pid`)
  LEFT JOIN `forums` `fp` ON (`f`.`first_post` = `fp`.`id`) 
  LEFT JOIN `ps` `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `f`.`author_guid`)
  LEFT JOIN `ps` `a` ON (`a`.`account_id` = `fr`.`author`)
```

My problem is this left join:

```
SELECT `a`.`name`, `a`.`level`
[..]
LEFT JOIN `ps` `a` ON (`a`.`account_id` = `fr`.`author`)
```

Since, in case `a` has MANY rows and it'll return like in my case:

```
NAME  | LEVEL
Test1 | 1
Test2 | 120
Test3 | 2
Test4 | 1
```

I want it to select `a.name` with `order` of level `desc` and limit 1, so it'll return the name of higher `level` where `(a.account_id = fr.author)`.

Hope you got me. If not, feel free to post a comment.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
LEFT JOIN ps a ON a.account_id = fr.author
```

with:

```
LEFT JOIN ps a 
  ON a.PrimaryKey                         --- the Primary Key of ps
     = ( SELECT b.PrimaryKey 
         FROM ps AS b 
         WHERE b.account_id = fr.author
         ORDER BY b.level DESC
         LIMIT 1
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the LEFT JOIN clause with something like:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.account_id, b.name
             FROM (SELECT c.account_id, MAX(c.level) AS level
                     FROM ps AS c
                    GROUP BY c.account_id) AS d
             JOIN ps AS b ON b.account_id = d.account_id AND b.level = d.level
          ) AS a
       ON (a.account_id = fr.author)
...
```

This will still return multiple rows if there were several rows in `ps` with the same account ID and the same level and that level was the maximum level:

```
NAME  | LEVEL
Test1 | 1
Test2 | 120
Test3 | 2
Test4 | 1
Test5 | 120
```

If this situation can arise, then you have to decide what you want to do - and tune the query appropriately.  For example, you might decide to use `MAX(b.name)` with a GROUP BY clause to arbitrarily select the alphabetically later of the two names.

Comment: Getting this error message: ` Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias'`
My query: http://pastebin.com/cDgxH8wG

Comment: try adding `as d` last on line 10

Comment: I've replaced the updated version and now: ` Column 'a.name' in field list is ambiguous'`

Comment: @Cyclone: You hadn't replaced the old LEFT JOIN. Try this version: http://pastebin.com/ShZEtDBf