# mysql - Limit a query with left join

Tags: mysql, left-join, limit

I have 2 tables like this:

Table person

```
id | name
---------
1  | john
2  | mike
3  | carl
4  | keny
5  | anna
```

Table vehicle

```
owner | vechicle
----------------
1     | RTA457
3     | GSW684
3     | GKI321
3     | SNE798
5     | YTT662
```

So, I want to make a query joining both tables, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN vehicle ON person.id=vehicle.owner
```

Getting these results

```
id | name | owner | vechicle
----------------------------
1  | john | 1     | RTA457
2  | mike | NULL  | NULL
3  | carl | 3     | GSW684
3  | carl | 3     | GKI321
3  | carl | 3     | SNE798
4  | keny | NULL  | NULL
5  | anna | 5     | YTT662
```

Finally, I want to limit it to 3 persons, showing all their vehicles, like this:

```
id | name | owner | vechicle
----------------------------
1  | john | 1     | RTA457
2  | mike | NULL  | NULL
3  | carl | 3     | GSW684
3  | carl | 3     | GKI321
3  | carl | 3     | SNE798
```

There is any way to do it?

Comment: How do you want to decide which 3 people to limit to? You need to order your query somehow. So, in general, you could SELECT ID from Person where XXX order by xxxx limit 3. Use the results of that as a subquery to select from the vehicle table.

Comment: The 3 first ones, just like a "LIMIT 3", the order is not relevant. the subquery idea sounds good, sadly I can not figure it how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May help with a subquery

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 3) t
LEFT JOIN vehicle ON t.id = vehicle.owner
```

Comment: This worked for me, a good idea, and I could add more subqueries like this separated by comas.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try it, but something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM person
LEFT JOIN vehicle ON person.id = vehicle.owner
WHERE person.id IN (SELECT ID FROM PERSON LIMIT 3);
```

Comment: it gives me this error: "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Corrected. Changed = to IN

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have your query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN vehicle ON person.id=vehicle.owner LIMIT 10;
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788212/left-join-order-and-limit) could be handy as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, How to limit it to 3 persons? (just like the example)

Comment: @stramin you can simply change 10 to 3. If my answer helped you vote it or if it answers your question do mark it as an answer so that it can help the others. Thanks :)