# Mysql:limit in join query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query for select all collections along with `image_name`

```
 SELECT
    cushbu_art.image_name,
    cushbu_user_collections.collection_name
FROM
    cushbu_art
JOIN cushbu_art_collections ON cushbu_art.id = cushbu_art_collections.art_id
LEFT JOIN cushbu_user_collections ON cushbu_user_collections.id = cushbu_art_collections.collection_id
```

Now i want to select only 3 rows from `cushbu_art`  table (ie need to apply limit on this `JOIN cushbu_art_collections ON cushbu_art.id = cushbu_art_collections.art_id` )

I found a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788212/left-join-order-and-limit) question but i can't understand the solution from it

**UPDATE**

Current query returns this

```
collection_name image_name

test-collection  test1.jpg
test-collection  test2.jpg
test-collection  test3.jpg
hello-collection hello.jpg
```

collection name `test-collection` repeated three times becacuse the child table (cushbu_art) contains three image for one collection
So i would like to apply a LIMIT on  `cushbu_art.image_name`

Expected output

```
    collection_name image_name

    test-collection  test1.jpg
    test-collection  test2.jpg
    hello-collection hello.jpg
```

Here is my latest query

```
SELECT
    cushbu_art.image_name,
    cushbu_user_collections.collection_name
FROM
    cushbu_art
JOIN cushbu_art_collections ON cushbu_art.id =(
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        cushbu_art
    WHERE
        cushbu_art.id = cushbu_art_collections.art_id
    LIMIT 1
)
LEFT JOIN cushbu_user_collections ON cushbu_user_collections.id = cushbu_art_collections.collection_id
```

Comment: You should give mysql a helping hand by aliasing cushbu_art_collections

Comment: Can't understand what your'e meaning

Comment: Really this question is voted up without anny example data en desired result?

Comment: @RaymondNijland updated my question with expected output

Comment: In your expected output, why are there two images name (test1.jpg, test2.jpg)  per one collection name **test-collection**?

Comment: Its beacuse each collection  can have more than one image its a one to many realtion with `cushbu_art` table