# MySQL - Left join order being ignored

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I'm attempting to order a join table by it's primary key `DESC` and pull out only that record to add to the dataset.

## Structure

### ws_results

- ResultID (P)
- ResultDateTime
- ResultServer
- ResultWinner

### ws_map

- dataID (p)
- resultID (linking to result table via ID)
- controlVS
- controlNC
- controlTR

## Query

```
SELECT 
    results.ResultID,
    results.ResultDateTime,
    results.ResultServer,
    results.ResultWinner,
    map.resultID,
    map.dataID,
    map.vs,
    map.nc,
    map.tr
FROM ws_results AS results
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        dataID,
        resultID,
        controlVS AS vs,
        controlNC AS nc,
        controlTR as tr
    FROM ws_map
    ORDER BY dataID DESC
) AS map ON map.resultID = results.ResultID 
WHERE results.ResultID = 38538
GROUP BY results.resultID
```

The above returns:
[image]

But it's incorrect, because if I run the subquery in it's own query like so:

```
SELECT
    dataID,
    resultID,
    controlVS AS vs,
    controlNC AS nc,
    controlTR as tr
FROM ws_map
WHERE resultID = 38538
ORDER BY dataID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[image]

The results don't match up, notice the `dataID` being incorrect in the first set of results, even though they're both ordered and have the same criteria.

I've tried everything from using `ORDER BY map.dataID DESC` but doesn't seem to work. I've also checked out the answer here: [LEFT JOIN order and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788212/left-join-order-and-limit) using `ON map.dataID = (SUBQUERY)` but that doesn't seem to work for my case either.

Comment: the order of the subquery is unuseful for the join ..  the order is for presenting the data the join for select the data  .. the two concept are different

Comment: A table has no order. The same goes for a derived table, i.e. a subquery in the from clause. Your `ORDER BY` clause gets ignored. And anyway, why do you expect your `GROUP BY results.resultID` to result in the first map row? You are not specifying which values you want from the map. You get just one `map.dataID`, one `map.vs`, etc, arbitrarily chosen. They could even reside in different records. Your query violates the standard and would result in an error in about every other DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've explained in the comments section, why your query cannot work. You are relying on a superfluous `ORDER BY` and you are using `GROUP BY` incorrectly.

Here is one way to achieve what you want: to get the best matching map record (the one with the highest dataID) per results record.

Select the maximum dataID per resultID and use this to access the according record.

```
SELECT 
  results.resultid,
  results.resultdatetime,
  results.resultserver,
  results.resultwinner,
  map.resultid as map_resultid,
  map.dataid,
  map.vs,
  map.nc,
  map.tr
FROM ws_results AS results
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    resultid,
    max(dataid) as dataid
  FROM ws_map
  GROUP BY resultid
) best ON best.resultid = results.resultid
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    dataid,
    resultid,
    controlvs as vs,
    controlnc as nc,
    controltr as tr
  FROM ws_map
) AS map ON map.resultid = best.resultid 
         AND map.dataid = best.dataid
WHERE results.resultid = 38538;
```

Comment: Ahh yes I didn't think to use `MAX` to figure out the top ID. I also didn't realise that `JOIN` ignored `ORDER BY`, I see I still have quite a lot to learn regarding SQL. Thank you for your solution!